# Why use defaults/preferences/*.js vs setting Firefox Add-on defaults in JavaScript?

Tags: firefox-addon

The more I think about it, I wonder why should anyone bother to use the defaults/preferences/*.js file to set defaults, versus setting the defaults in JavaScript?

I am doing work on an older XUL/Overlay based add-on created by someone else, which actually uses a prefs.js file in addition to setting all the defaults in the JavaScript (in case the prefs.js failed for some inexplicable reason?), which essentially makes all the preferences into user-prefs directly after installation.  This confused me at first, as the defaults were showing up as modified (user-set) when looking at the prefs in `about:config`.  Then I realized it was unconditionally setting some of the defaults (very large strings).

So I realized, not only do I maintain the same prefs in 3 locations (prefs.js, interface and content scripts), but the prefs.js file is largely redundant, which seems to add additional maintenance for no reason.  This just seems silly, and I am looking for a better way, to just store prefs and manage them in one location (which probably is why the prefs.js should be used exclusively).

Now, I realize, this question has the potential to be flagged as an "opinion", and may or may not have a specific "right" answer.  But I think it is a valid question, and I would like to learn more about the pros and cons of using a prefs.js file, versus setting all prefs during initialization in a shared JS code.  Are there any performance concerns, or objective list of criteria that I could use to make this determination?  Is it possible that the prefs.js mechanism would ever fail?  Is it safe to assume it never will fail?  Was it more prone to failure back in the FF 1.0-3.5 days?

Comment: I personally don't use `defaults/preferences` I hold the default value in js, and if the pref is not present I use the default value from my js. I feel like there is no need to clutter up a file that is accessed synchronously when the info is already in my code. So its really up to you. I personally feel it's better to do it without defaults/pref/*.js - but the the perf difference is immeasurable (i havent even tried).

Comment: Thank you for the perspective.  I am still quite new to add-on development, and as I learn more, some things just seem confusing or silly.  Then I wonder if I am missing something due to my ignorance and inexperience, or if it is something others have noticed and dealt with in better ways than I.  The docs all scream up and down, "make sure you put all your preferences there, make sure, no really, do it, make sure you do it, did you do it, you did it, right?  Well ok then."  Then you go and find out it is just as redundant as you thought, or slightly worse.  I did use it, but may revert later.

Comment: The problem with the `defaults/preferences`, is that it is not JavaScript.  Just a glorified plain text config, with rigid syntax and minimal type checking.  No execution.  If you want to select a preference at run-time based on system parameters, then you have preference code creeping into add-on code and cluttering things up, creating ambiguity.  Where you could create a module with all the preferences, and all the objects and methods and properties needed to manage them.  That would seem simpler to maintain, debug and review, etc.  Anyone w/opposing views, with good reasons, I'm listening.

Comment: Excellent observerations. One main reason why I don't use `defaults/prefernes` is because on uninstall of the addon it is not **as easy** as if I had done it without defaults. One reason **i think ** they recommended `defaults/preferenes` in the past is because they expected users to go to `about:config` and change preferences. However now we present a nice options pane, easily do able. So preferences should only be changed from there. And the pref branch should only be used for persistance. That's what I beleive. In summary - i dont set defaults, the defaults are default getter in my code.

Comment: Ah, I read ahead a little, and this is apparently [Step 4: Manually handle default prefererences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/How_to_convert_an_overlay_extension_to_restartless#Step_4_Manually_handle_default_preferences) on the process to migrate from overlay to restartless on my way to sdk, so my intuition was correct despite being on Step 1.  Thanks again for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Default preferences:

- Can be changed in a new version of the add-on without overriding the value set explicitly by the user.
- Do not clutter up the user's profile after the add-on is uninstalled
- Are located in the same place, not scattered thoughout the code. It's easy to see what preferences there are. They also appear in about:config, which allows you to have UI for "hidden" prefs - for the sake of power users.

It *is* a pity they did not make the get*Pref API return the default value in case the user-set value is invalid, and I understand not wanting to maintain the default in two locations. This whole API was "frozen" a long time ago, and will eventually go away with the rest of XPCOM, so it doesn't really matter...

Comment: In my question and comments, I refer to the usage of the default prefs file used for distribution/installation rather than the runtime mechanism of the default prefs branch.  I have found that both name and type changes to my default prefs file left unused or broken (respectively) user prefs behind, even after uninstall.  And additionally, more than half the prefs were never put into the default prefs file.  So none of your points were valid in my experience.  But the last point is handy as a developer and troubleshooting planned updates, etc.  But yes, it's at end of life now.

Comment: What I learned from managing the prefs was that it's up to the programmer to put the defaults in a handy and visible place.  To handle any changes to pref names or types before pref loading.  I maybe went overboard here, but keep a "change buffer" so to speak, a little object that holds the minimal details about such changes, which I pass to an updatePrefs method of my own prefs object, which has a generic getPref.  But a generic setPref is futile.  INTs pulled from XUL elements are strings.  FLOATS and UNSIGNED INT (timestamps) are stored as STRINGS, because prefs INT is signed-only, mangles.

Comment: So if I decide I need to move prefs from one branch to another, or change the names to be more self-documenting, or change the code to require a different data type, I put such details in my little change prefs object, pass it to my method, add new names, copy old values, convert data types, delete old pref names, or delete old branches.  So any user that comes back to this add-on during my revival, won't get strange errors based on major changes to the way I name, values I store, or methods to get and set prefs, easy to i.e. move XUL root-based non-GUID prefs to GUID specific location for SDK

Comment: Ah, thank you for the reminder about making sure I handle the uninstall properly.  Currently I do not think I am properly scrubbing user prefs.  They just sort of sit there forever.  ^_^